# Match 11 or 13 digits using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a code where I am receiving a number of exactly 11 or 13 digits in it. But, the problem is that it may contain some hyphens at random places.
Can anyone suggest a regular expression for this?
Sample inputs (assuming only 5 digits):

`1. 12345
2. 1-234-5
3. 12-34-5
4. 123-45
5. 1-2-34-5`

Comment: remove all non digits and then use count. NEXT!

Comment: (^[\d-]{11,13}$) use this.

Comment: you can use replace ...

Comment: @vks: This will match `------------` or `123456789012` (12 digits).

Answer (score 3):

Try this code snippet. It may help you.

```
var str="123-45";
str.replace( /\D+/g, '');
```

Here,

\D - Find a non-digit character.
so, Code will replace non-digit with ''.

Comment: Please explain why this should be the solution, it will make your answer more useful, eg for novice users.

Comment: This solution removes all the symbol and character except NUMBER, So it will help in any condition.It is a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

It would be significantly easier, and infinitely more readable to remove all dashes, and then count the remaining characters.

```
var str = "1-234-5";
var res = str.replace(/-/g, '').length;
if(res === 11 || res === 13) {
    //do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

```
^(?:-?\d){11}(?:-?\d-?\d)?$
```

or, if `-` can't be in first place:

```
^(?:\d-?){11}(?:\d-?\d)?$
```